# Looping vue object in express/sql

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

I have a form that adds a project with x number of persons.

I'm using Nuxt with express and MySQL database.

I have a route method like this that inserts a project to my database:

```
app.post('/addNewProject', function (req, res) {
  var sql = "INSERT INTO project (name, startDate, endDate) VALUES ('"+req.body.projectName+"', '"+req.body.projectStart+"', '"+req.body.projectEnd+"'); INSERT INTO persons (projectID, name, workHours) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '"+req.body.persons[0].personName+"', '"+req.body.persons[0].personHours+"')";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(rows)
  })
})
```

The `persons` is a vue object `persons: [{ personName: '', personHours: '' }],` that can be filled in  the form.

So since its `persons[0]` now, it only adds the first item to the database.

**Im wondering if there is a way to loop the object inside this sql variable.**

And I think I have to loop it here since I need the LAST_INSERT_ID() because I need to get the `projectID` that is a AUTO_INCREMENT primary key in the project table.

I have tried to use sql wihle loop but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Serialize the array, provide it into the query, parse and store. I recommend you to create stored procedure which performs all insertions and call it instead of a bunch of separate queries. PS. What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina Sounds complicated. I'm using MariaDB 10.4.17 locally with XAMPP.

Comment: For this DBMS version I recommend you to serialize the array into single CSV/TSV value and parse in the query using recursive CTE.